# How to scan input integers line by line?

Tags: java, input

We want to write a program to solve two `"Ax2+Bx+C=0"` form equations.

When coefficients of equations `Ax2+Bx+C=0` are entered 1 line per equation, it may look like the following:

```
2   3       // linear equation when the coefficient for the term x2 is zero

4   5   6   // quadratic equation
```

nextInt() won't tell us whether 4 is the third number of the first line or the first number of the second line. That is, the below input will return exactly the same information.

```
2   3   4    // quadratic equation

5   6          // linear equation
```

Both inputs are also no different from `2 3 4 5 6` for nextInt()

So how can I scan those coefficients line by line?

Answer (score 4):

Get each line at a time with Scanner's `nextLine()`, and then use `String#split(" ")` to get the individual tokens in their proper order. You can easily find out how many tokens are present by getting the returned array's length. You'll of course need to parse the token Strings returned via `Integer.parseInt(...)`.

Comment: Or you could use a Scanner on that String too

Comment: @Thikan: Yep yep! Just be sure to close each Scanner when done using it so as not to run out of resources.

Comment: Many thanks to all, I think the most elegant way is to use a Scanner on that String, that will be much more easier!

Answer (score 0):

**-** Use `nextLine()` method of Scanner.

**Eg:**

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

String l = scan.nextLine();
```

**-** Use split() with " " (space) as a delimeter to get every value.

```
String[] arr = l.split(" ");
```

**-** Use the `Integer.parseInt()` to convert it **back to int**.

```
ArrayList<Integer> aList = ArrayList<Integer>();

for (String s : arr){

     aList.add(Integer.parseInt(s));

}
```